# Archivos PHP en Electron, que hacer?

Tags: php, electron

hace unos dias empece a estudiar sobre el framework Electron, puesto que necesito hacer una aplicación de escritorio para la Universidad, pero presento unas dudas que no logro resolver.

Soy completamente nuevo en Electron y por el momento solo he logrado que jQuery se cargue correctamente para que los **data-toggle** funcionen correctamente. Y actualmente me estoy documentando en cómo establecer la conexión a una Base de Datos con MySQL en Electron.

Estoy haciendo las pruebas con un sistema muy simple de Facturación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me he dado cuenta de que los archivos PHP que tengo para los listados no funcionan y se carga es el codigo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como he dicho, soy nuevo en Electron y no estoy muy al tanto, tengo entendido que Electron no soporta PHP (lo cual no entiendo bien puesto que el index que uso en el proyecto de prueba es .php y funciona como se puede ver en las imágenes) entonces tengo dudas sobre que debo hacer en ese caso, **hay forma de implementar PHP?** **Debo usar otra cosa?** **O que otras soluciones puedo aplicar?**. Espero que alguien pueda sacarme esas dudas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En efecto, Electron no soporta PHP, y probablemente el `index.php` se vea bien porque es HTML y Electron lo trata como tal en vez de como PHP.
Lo que puedes hacer para usar PHP, es iniciar un servidor local internamente usando [node-php-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-php-server).

Otra opción sería utilizar algo como [phpdesktop](https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop).

Comment: Gracias por las recomendaciones, las voy a mirar.

Answer (score 0):

Para conectarte a una base de datos desde *Electron* tienes que hacerlo desde un archivo *JavaScript*. Además del archivo `index.js` para correr la aplicación, crea un archivo llamado `database.js` en ese archivo estableces la conexión con tu servidor local (o cualquiera que sea tu caso), en la siguiente imagen te dejo un ejemplo.

> **PD:** Para poder hacer la conexión necesitar instalar **promise-mysql**, para hacerlo ve a la terminal integrada de VsCode y ejecuta el comando `npm i promise-mysql`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]